# Cannot find module with absolute import Next+TS+Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, next.js

I am using absolute imports and
testing a component with Context Provider in a NextJS project.
I have set this up according to [jest setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/)

TEST:

```
import { render, screen } from 'test-util';

import { Sidebar } from '@/components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
  test('if it has a brand image', () => {
    render(<Sidebar />);
    const brandLogo = screen.getByAltText('logo');
    expect(brandLogo).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Here is my `test-util.tsx` in the root folder.

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { AuthProvider } from 'store/auth';

const AllTheProviders: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>;
};

const customRender = (ui: ReactElement, options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export { customRender as render };
```

This is my `jest.config.js` in the root folder

```
// @ts-nocheck
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '^@/pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
    '^@/firebase/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/firebase/$1',
    '^@/store/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/store/$1',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Here is `jest.setup.js` in the root folder

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

I get this error:

```
 FAIL  components/Sidebar/__test__/Sidebar.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'test-util' from 'components/Sidebar/__test__/Sidebar.test.tsx'

      1 | import { Sidebar } from '@/components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
    > 2 | import { render } from 'test-util';
        |                                   ^
      3 |
```

Here is `tsconfig.paths.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/pages/*": ["./pages/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@/features/*": ["./features/*"],
      "@/firebase/*": ["./firebase/*"],
      "@/store/*": ["./store/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

How to solve this issue? I want to use

```
import { render, screen } from 'test-util';
```

What works:

```
import { render, screen } from '../../../test-util';

import { Sidebar } from '@/components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
  test('if it has a brand image', () => {
    render(<Sidebar />);
    const brandLogo = screen.getByAltText('logo');
    expect(brandLogo).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: You need to use a relative path to point to your `test-util.tsx` file, i.e. `../../../test-util` (assuming the file is in the project root).

Comment: It does work with `../../../test-util` but I esnt it to use 'import { render } from 'test-util';' absolute path, as I have done with components.

Comment: Then you need to configure a path alias for it like you did for the other folders.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar config, but it works for me.

Try to add `moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/"]`
inside your `customJestConfig` object.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem and

```
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
```

in `customJestConfig` helped me